# Order by descending then ascending same column

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

How would I get sql to order the same column differently depending on conditions? Like in the example below, if `n/s` is `n`, then `order by distfromc desc`, if not then `order by distfromc asc`, so to appear like the table below.

```
name  n/s  distfromc
BH    n    2
FV    n    1
C     c    0
RS    s    1
MTN   s    2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT tablename.*
FROM tablename
ORDER BY
  `n/s` = 'n' DESC,
  CASE WHEN `n/s` = 'n' THEN distfromc END DESC,
  CASE WHEN `n/s` != 'n' THEN distfromc END ASC
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff243/1).